# Better way to build lists of matches in parser generator

Tags: erlang, parser-generator

(I use Yecc, an Erlang parser generator similar to Yacc, so the syntax is different from Yacc)

The problem is simple, say we want parse a lispy syntax, i want match on expressions-lists.
An expression list is a list of expressions separated with blank space.

In Erlang, `[1,3,4]` is a list and `++` concatenates two lists.

We want match this `1 (1+2) 3`. `expression` will match 1, (1+2) and 3. So, there i match on the list followed by one more expression, and if there is no match i end to match on a single expression. This builds a list recursively.

```
expressionlist -> expressionlist expression : '$1' ++ ['$2'].
expressionlist -> expression : ['$1'].
```

But i can do this too (invert the order):

```
expressionlist -> expression expressionlist : ['$1']  ++ '$2'.
expressionlist -> expression : ['$1'].
```

Both of theese seem to work, i would like to know if there was any difference.

**With a separator**

I want to match `{name = albert , age = 43}`. `propdef` matches `name = value`. So it is the same problem but with an additional separator `,`. Is there any difference there from the first problem ?

```
proplist -> propdef ',' proplist  :  ['$1'] ++ '$3'.
proplist -> propdef  :  ['$1'].
proplist -> '{' proplist '}' :  '$2'.
proplist -> '{' '}' :  [].

%% Could write this
%% proplist -> proplist ',' propdef :  '$1' ++ ['$3'].
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to write a clear title for this one in english. Change it at will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Yecc is an LALR parser generator, the use of left recursion or right recursion doesn't matter much. In old times, people would prefer left recursion in Yacc/Bison and similar tools because it allows the parser to keep reducing instead of shifting everything onto the stack until the end of the list, but these days, stack space and speed isn't that important, so you can pick whatever suits you best. (Note that in an LL parser, left recursion causes an infinite loop, so for such parsers, right recursion is necessary.)

The more important thing, for your example above, is that '$1' ++ ['$2'] in the left recursive version will cause quadratic time complexity, since the "expressionlist" part is the one that's going to be longer and longer. You should never have the growing component on the left when you use the ++ operator. If you parse a list of thousands of elements, this complexity will hurt you. Using the right recursive version instead, ['$1']  ++ '$2' will give you linear time, even if the parser has to shift the whole list onto the stack before it starts reducing. You could try both versions and parse a really long list to see the difference.

Using a separator as in "propdef ',' proplist" does not change the problem.

Comment: "You should never have the growing component on the left when you use the ++ operator" Ok just like in plain erlang, right. When the growing element is on the left it's called left recursion otherwise it is right recusrsion, is that true ? (or is it more complex ?). So if there is no differecence on the result i'll choose right recursion

Comment: "Left recursion" and "Right recursion" are properties of your grammar: "expressionlist -> expressionlist expression" is left recursive, and "expressionlist -> expression expressionlist" is right recursive. The ++ operator is a different thing: you should avoid having the growing component on the left, but it's unrelated to how your grammar looks.

Comment: yes there is no strong relation between how i match code and how i build tree. So, thanks :)

Comment: You still want left recursive rules/trees with LALR.  People build ridiculously long lists; we've encountered C programs with array initializers of 1 million items.   If you right-recurse your rule, this tends to blow any reasonable size stack, and is one of the many reaonable arguments IMHO against LL.

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, in languages with limited stack size you need to do that. But in Erlang, and as long as you're not expecting to run in a system where memory is tight, stack is not a big deal. On the other hand, the quadratic complexity of the append in the left recursive version is a killer. To avoid that in a left recursive rule, you need to build the result in reverse (appending new elements to the left) and reverse the result when the end of the list is reached. However, that will use the heap as scratch instead of the stack, and put more load on the GC, so it's (slightly) slower.

Comment: @RichardC:  We in fact have a heap-based activation record scheme, but still 1 million activation records that we don't end up holding live is a lot of space in which to build the AST.  "The append"? Quadratic? For building the tree under that list rule? a) its a representation, and it doesn't matter if the leftmost node  is deepest in the linear-time time left-leaning tree (some node has to be deepest), and b) if you use a list-node for list-rules, your insertion times are linear in the number of list-insertion steps, which can be very fast if your list management is designed sensibly.

Comment: @IraBaxter This is Erlang - lists are singly linked and immutable. ['$1']  ++ '$2' takes O(1) time, since it just adds a new node pointing to '$2', while '$1' ++ ['$2'] takes time O(|'$1'|) (compare copying an immutable string to build a new, larger string). Since the semantic action will be performed for each element in the input, making '$1' larger and larger, the right recursive version above will take time O(N^2). Also, even if an activation record can be larger than an AST node, a million records of (say) 128 bytes each (16 64-bit words) is still just 128 MB. My browser uses twice that.